# Duplicated mapping in serverless

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I'm using Serverless to deploy a functions written in nodejs to AWS.

I was getting an error    Cannot parse "serverless.yml": duplicated mapping key.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hTMj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have two `http` in your yml file, remove one of them.

If you want to run it on every request and any type, you can do this:

```yaml
function:
  api:
    handler: lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: '*'
          path: /
```

*Sidenote: You should probably give it an endpoint and request method to be on the safer side.*